# Requesting Data from Tableau Server Using Rest API

Tags: rest, angular, tableau-api

I currently have a windows server set up and I am looking to make rest API calls using Angular 2 to the Tableau Server.

The problem  becomes that the Tableau Server that our company uses is over SSL, and my connection is not.

Before I start looking into an SSL certificate I would like to make sure that what I am trying to do is possible. 
If I were to add the SSL certificate to the server would this remove my error upon making the request?

I Get an error when making my HTTP post request to an HTTPS server, `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONCE`.

If I purchase (or get a  free trial) a SSL certificate, what kind would I need to do this.

Comment: Try a self-signed certificate first before spending money on a certificate. That might be enough to test with.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll look into that now.

I had also thought about setting up a python server to make the Rest Api calls and send the information back to the angular2 application.